# What's the difference between struct and typealias in swift?

Tags: swift, struct, type-alias

I want to have an array with one string and one integer in it. What's the difference between:

```
struct People { var name: String!; var age: Int! };
var data = Array<People>();
data.append (People(name: "John Doe", age: 31));
```

with:

```
typealias People = (name: String!, age: Int!);
var data = Array<People>();
data.append ((name: "John Doe", age: 31));
```

in terms of everything other than that. I mean, is there any difference in accessing the data, memory management, pointer-issue things, or something else I should be wary of when switching from struct to typealias? I usually use struct, but then I just found that I have typealias as alternative. I just want to make sure which one is better for my daily use. Note: I notice that struct is much like class in terms of you can add methods in there. But for things like that, I usually straight up using class.

Comment: There's at least one significant similarity: Both snippets don't compile ;-)

Comment: @vadian ;_; I have fixed it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are comparing a `struct` with the `typealias of a tuple`.

A struct is much more powerful than a tuple, here's some advantages only a struct offers

1. a struct can conform to a **protocol**, a tuple can't
2. a struct can have **methods**, a tuple can't
3. a struct can have **computed properties**, a tuple can't
4. a struct can have **initializers**, a tuple can't

### Considerations

I suggest you to use a **struct** for your model. It's a better fit for a model value.

Someday you'll need to add a computed property (like `birthYear`) to your type and you don't want to be constrained by the limitations of simple tuple.

Comment: I see. That is quite a strong argument you have there for struct. Yeah, sometimes I use computed properties in class, and I definitely don't want to be constrained when I want to add that. I do thinking about making models. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Structures and tuples have different purposes.

Use tuples in scenario when you `temporary` need couple related data. It should **not define** any new entities (for example `Person`).

For example use a tuple when returning multiple values from a function:

```
func operations(a: Int, b: Int) -> (Int, Int) {
  return (a + b, a * b)
}
let (mySum, myMul) = operations(10, 5)
mySum // => 15
myMul // => 50
```

The tuple that returns `operations()` exists temporary until its data is extracted into variables `mySum` and `myMul`.

---

The structure couples related data for longterm usage. And additionally allows to define methods that operate on structure's data (plus everything related like inheritance, conforming to protocols).
Use it to **define the entities** and their behavior in the application, for example like you do for `People`.

Comment: Ah I see now the different philosophical usage between those two. I think I'll stick to my struct then! But now I know the proper time when to use the tuple. Thanks!